# Why did Edward break Jacob's arm?

Tags: twilight

In Twilight : Breaking Dawn (Part 1), right after Jacob wanted to kill Bella's daughter and then stopped (imprint scene), Edward read through Jacob's mind, then broke his arm and threw him.

**Is that because he saw he wanted to kill his daughter ? Or because of the imprint scene he knew his daughter will be related to Jacob's in a way.**

*Didn't see part 2 yet.*

Comment: If this wasn't clear at the end of part 1, then it will *definitely* be clear at towards the beginning of part 2 since another character (which I'm sure you can imagine who) has a similar reaction. Also, this scene in the book removes any doubt about the motivations.

Answer (score 1):

It was because he read Jacobs thoughts and knew he imprinted and wanted him to stay safe out of the fight in the house and keep close watch and protect Renesme.
That is why it was a simple injury.  He could have done much worse.

Answer (score -1):

i think it was the fact jacob wanted to kill renesme and it infuriated edward cuz the wolves were surrounding them he may have thought jacob was gonna double cross them by allowing the pack come in and to attack

Comment: Do you have anything to back up your answer?